# Can we have different custom drawer contents

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I have to Drawer Screens. Both require custom drawer content. I like to know if we can have one custom drawer content for HomeDrawer and a completely different drawer content for the PanelDrawer

```
<Drawer.Navigator
              initialRouteName="HomeDrawer"
              edgeWidth={0}
              // swipeEdgeWidth={0}
              drawerContent={props => <DrawerContent {...props} />}>
              <Drawer.Screen
                name="HomeDrawer"
                options={{
                  title: headerTitleEnabled ? 'Hello App' : '',
                  headerStyle: {
                    backgroundColor: Colors.primary,
                  },
                  headerTintColor: '#fff',
                  headerRight: props => <HeaderButtons {...props} />,
                }}
                component={MainTabNavigator}
              />
              <Drawer.Screen
                name="PanelDrawer"
                options={{
                  title: headerTitleEnabled ? 'Hello App' : '',
                  headerStyle: {
                    backgroundColor: Colors.primary,
                  },
                  headerTintColor: '#fff',
                  headerRight: props => (
                    <HeaderButtonsCustom{...props} />
                  ),
                }}
                component={CustomLayoutNavigator}
              />
```

Answer (score 0):

Of course, you can nest the drawers if that's the case you want:

> Nesting navigators means rendering a navigator inside a screen of another navigator

```
const MainDrawer = createDrawerNavigator();
const HomeDrawer = createDrawerNavigator();
const PanelDrawer = createDrawerNavigator();

const HomeScreen = () => (
  <HomeDrawer.Navigator>
    {/*Home drawer custom stuff*/}
  </HomeDrawer.Navigator>
);

const PanelScreen = () => (
  <PanelDrawer.Navigator>
    {/*Panel drawer custom stuff*/}
  </PanelDrawer.Navigator>
);

const Navigator = () => (
  <MainDrawer.Navigator>
    <MainDrawer.Screen name="HomeScreen" component={HomeScreen} />
    <MainDrawer.Screen name="PanelScreen" component={PanelScreen} />
  </MainDrawer.Navigator>
);
```

You can read more about nesting navigators in the [official documentation](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/nesting-navigators/).